# Nyquist plot from transfer function with quartic polinominal in denominator

Tags: matlab, maple, transfer-function, nyquist

So I have some very large and difficult transfer function, after some expanding and collecting by 's' in maple, i convert this to matlab and try to get nyquist plot, but this doesnt work. I am realy noob in this, why i cant take some plot. Also bode plot works fine.

There is my real code in matlab:

```
s = tf('s');
H1_e = tf ([-Mst_pr K3+2*K5 2*C3-C5], [Mch*Mst_pr (-K1-K5)*Mst_pr+Mch*(-K3-K5) (-C1-C3)*Mst_pr+(-K1-K5)*(-K3-K5)+Mch*(-C3+C5)-K5^2 (-C1-C3)*(-K3-K5)+(-K1-K5)*(-C3+C5)-C3*K5+K5*C5 (-C1-C3)*(-C3+C5)+C3*C5])
nyquist (H1_e);
```

After this my plot is just empty with real and img axis.

Also there is a real transfer function with substitution of all parameters:

```
H1_e =

             -17.65 s^2 + 12000 s + 7.996e09
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 352.9 s^4 - 2.553e05 s^3 - 1.558e11 s^2 + 5.13e13 s + 1.72e19
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Ok i have some suggestion. Is it because free radicals is too large than others coefs - 1.72e19 and 7.996e09?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not invisible, you just can't see it. Due to the fact that you have very high coefficients.
By zooming you can actually see something

[image]

As you can see the imaginary part is ~10^(-10) and the real part is ~10^(-3).
To avoid this problems it's usual to normalize the transfer function in such a way that the lowest order term has value 1.